# Matplotlib absolute text positioning

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making movies from matplotlib plots and have been struggling with the absolute positioning of `text()` elements. The problem is that my text blocks, typically increasing numbers, keep moving around depending on which numbers are printed. It happens even when I set the horizontal/vertical alignment to a fixed level (e.g. `right` or `bottom`).

This seems to be related to my use of LaTeX fonts, in particular fonts where certain characters are wider than others. With the default font (Bitstream Vera Sans) it does not happen.

Here is an illustration of the problem. With the default font:

[image]

With the latex cmbright font:

[image]

Notice how the position of the decimal point shifts horizontally depending if the leading digit is 0, 1, or 2. In some other examples the decimal point shifts vertically. The following code was used to produce these plots:

```
figure(figsize=(4,4))
tt = text(.7, .5, '00.0', va='center', ha='right', fontsize=60)
for i in range(26):
    tt.set_text('%04.1f' % (float(i)))
    savefig(...)
```

For the LaTeX font I loaded the following before:

```
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{cmbright}')
```

I have tried different types of alignment, but I still can't get the point to be fixed. With `ha='right'` I thought that the right side was always at a fixed location. Changing the font is not really an option, as I need this one for consistency and other reasons. Any ideas on how to fix this problem? It leads to very unprofessional-looking videos.

Comment: This is due to latex using better (normally, anyway) kerning with some fonts.  You might see if there's a way to disable kerning for a specific piece of text in latex.  However, without using XeTex and the `fontspec` package, I'm not sure if there is...

Comment: You might get away with using a mono-space latex environment.  The other tricky thing is that the way latex + agg get along is the the latex is pre-processed into pngs which are then (cached and) inserted.    If the bounding box in ps2png is floating around you might also have these problems.

Comment: Thank you @JoeKington and @tcaswell. So far I could not succeed in using `fontspec` with matplotlib. Is there a way to use LuaLaTex instead of pdftex? I've made movies before (about ~1.5 yr ago, not sure which matplotlib version) with the same font that didn't have this problem, so I don't know if something has changed. Removing the `text` artist and starting anew instead of `set_text` also doesn't fix it. Also, using monospace through `\texttt` doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: In a latex table, you can align on a decimal point; maybe you could insert a minimal table, or maybe latex can align on decimals generally. The outer edges would still move in a non-fixed-width font, I think.

Comment: Is having four separate text artists an option for you (3 for the numbers, 1 for the dot)? You could position the number one anchored to their centers and ensure that the dot was fixed that way.